# Can't get MBP to recognize two external monitors

Tags: display, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

MBP: 13-inch, M2, 2022, 8GB RAM, Ventura 13.2.1

Setup:

```
Thunderbolt Display                     --> MBP USB-C Port 1
LG HDMI monitor     --> HODO 9-in-1 hub --> MBP USB-C Port 2
Charger             --> HODO 9-in-1 hub --> MBP USB-C Port 2
```

1. Thunderbolt display works fine.
2. Charge is correctly passed through hub to MBP.
3. LG monitor reports connected, but no signal.
4. If I disconnect the Thunderbolt display, the LG monitor gets signal and displays it.
5. Detecting displays in System Settings does nothing.

What I want:

Thunderbolt and LG both displaying. I don't need built-in display, plan to keep it with the lid down behind the two external monitors.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's [MacBook Pro (13-inch, M2, 2022) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP870?locale=en_US) state you can have only one external display. This is also reported at [everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-m2-8-core-cpu-10-core-gpu-13-2022-specs.html).

However, there is [DisplayLink](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics)...

> While this may work, I figure this can not be as good as having purchased a Mac which is designed to support more monitors.

So you install [software](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads) which allows for more displays. This software also compresses the video and evidently sends this through your Mac's existing USB, Thunderbolt, etc to external hardware such as a DisplayLink compatible adaptor or dock. This external hardware decompress the video. You then connect your monitor to a port on the external hardware, which can be HTML, DisplayPort, etc.

An example would be [OWC USB-C Dual HDMI 4K Display Adapter with DisplayLink](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/CADPDL2HDMI).

[image: OWC]

The website [explicitly states](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/CADPDL2HDMI#compatibility) this product is compatible with your Mac.

---

Synaptics provides a [website](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/displaylink-products-list) with DisplayLink supported docks and adaptors. There are filters to help limit the displayed products.

After searching the above website, I have concluded that might want to consider substituting a Thunderbolt 4 dock for your HODO 9-in-1 hub. This would allow you to connect your Thunderbolt display to the Thunderbolt dock. An example dock with similar capabilities of the [HODO 9-in-1 hub](https://www.amazon.com/stores/HODO/9IN1USBCHUBforMac/page/322A6117-E096-4CC0-AD3B-C0CD446001A0) would be this [OWC Thunderbolt Dock](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-dock).

[image: Dock]

In conclusion, I can say the following: *"You ain't spent enough money to get what you are asking for in your question."*

Comment: Many thanks for the research, very much appreciated.